# Folder listing in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

what I need to do is get a list of files in a folder in a Flex application from the web (i.e. all the files in a location like http://example.com/folder1).  Can anyone please help me.  Thank you.

Chris

Answer (score 2):

To get that the list of files in a server directory, you'd need to use a server-side script (.NET, php, Ruby, etc), then pass the list to your Flex app.

Would be something of a huge security issue if you could get that information within a client side Flex app natively...  unless you're using AIR on the desktop, in which case you have access to the file system.

Comment: I am not sure about the security aspect of your answer since the location is web accessible and the client is asking for the information from the server, but I do agree with the solution you provide

Comment: The security comment is more referring to the idea of the Flex app being able to natively read the info from the server, instead of via a service layer.  That's what it sounded like he was hoping for.

Comment: There is a security aspect to it - most of the web servers do not allow clients to list any random folder in its web-root - they block it using some rules in the server.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this example http://ntt.cc/2008/02/10/how-to-load-an-image-into-our-flex-application-from-url-with-source.html

Comment: I am not sure this article applies to this scenario since it is for loading an image that you know the location and the question is for getting a list of all the files at a folder location.